# Subviews is pushing down issue

Tags: ios7, storyboard

I am using storyboard to design a `ViewController`, but when I run the app the subview is pushing down and is not at same position in the `ViewController`. Why and how can I prevent it?

This is on storyboard:

[image: this is on storyboard]

This is when I run the app:

[image: this is when I run the app]

Comment: Check for the autolayout constraints of the subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In storyboard uncheck your Extend Edges `Under Top Bars` of your viewController,

[image]

Comment: you gave me good hint. when i uncheck your mention highlight option its working cool as i want. but ur ans you say check it? thats why i not promote your ans . please correct your sentence

Comment: @M.B: oh it may be typo. :)